# Dúvida Python, como que uma lista é iterada em uma repetição

Tags: python

Olá, o seguinte algoritmo relaciona as pessoas e as relações de amizade entre elas. Minha dúvida no entanto refere-se ao bloco de for indicado no código.

```
def not_the_same(user, other_user):
    return user["id"] != other_user["id"]

def not_friends(user, other_user):
    return all(not_the_same(friends, other_user)
                for friend in user["friends"])

def friends_of_friends_ids(user):
    return Counter(foaf["id"]
                   for friend in user["friends"] //dúvida
                   for foaf in friend["friends"] //nesse trecho
                   if not_the_same(user,foaf)
                   and not_friends(user,foaf))
users = [
{"id":0,"name":"Hero"},
{"id":1,"name":"Dunn"},
{"id":2,"name":"Sue"},
{"id":3,"name":"Chi"},
{"id":4,"name":"Thor"},
{"id":5,"name":"Clive"},
{"id":6,"name":"Hicks"},
{"id":7,"name":"Devin"},
{"id":8,"name":"Kate"},
{"id":9,"name":"Klein"}
]

friendship = [(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),
              (4,5),(5,6),(5,7),(6,8),(7,8),(8,9)]

for user in users:
    user["friends"] = []

for i,j in friendship:
    users[i]["friends"].append(users[j])    #adicion i como um amigo de j 
    users[j]["friends"].append(users[i])    #adicion j como um amigo de i

friends_of_friends_id(users[3])
```

Na chamada de função `friends_of_friends_id(users[3])` passo a lista de users, porém somente o exposto no índice e que deveria representar apenas `{"friends":[1,2,4],"id":3,"name":"Chi"}`.

```
for friend in user["friends"]
    for foaf in friend["friends"] 
       if not_the_same(user,foaf)
       and not_friends(user,foaf)
```

No primeiro `for` entendo que ele acesse os valores da chave friends 1,2 e 4, mas no segundo for ele passa a váriavel que é usada no bloco for anterior friend para ser iterada como se a mesma fosse a lista do escopo global users(e funciona).

A minha dúvida é, se passei apenas a parte representada no índice `{"friends":[1,2,4],"id":3,"name":"Chi"}`, como ele pode acessar o restante dos índices? Entendo que python trabalha com referências mas não entendo como isso possa se aplicar aqui.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que você está tendo é um pouco antes do for citado no segundo `for`:

```
for i,j in friendship:
    users[i]["friends"].append(users[j])    #adicion i como um amigo de j 
    users[j]["friends"].append(users[i])    #adicion j como um amigo de i
```

Na realidade você está colocando toda referencia do dicionário daquele usuário na memória (`users[i]`). Se você der um print em users logo após este `for` poderá ver que ele não estará `{"friends":[1,2,4],"id":3,"name":"Chi"}`

O que acredito que você de fato queira é

```
for i,j in friendship:
    users[i]["friends"].append(j)    #adicion i como um amigo de j 
    users[j]["friends"].append(i)    #adicion j como um amigo de i
```